# Code of Discord.js on running not showing output

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello guys I am having problem when I try to run my discord.js code its not showing any out put it just shows this when I run code(I am using VS Code)
On running on vs code (with the Code Runner package)

```
[Running] node "d:\Red\Bot Devlopment Javascript\Src\index.js"

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.085 seconds
```

On running on cmd

```
d:\Red\Bot Devlopment Javascript\Src
```

My Bot Code

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()
const config = require('./config.json')

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The client is ready!')
})

client.login(config.token)
```

Please help me where should  I run my code or is there a problem in code itself

Answer (score 0):

In your code, everything is all right.

To run your node.js code, simply go to terminal in VS Code and run node . or, if that doesn't work, node index.js. You don't have to specify full path if you have correct workspace opened, and don't put it in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ending itself since you are passing in an invalid token.
You do not read json files using `require`, but you should use `fs`, a built in module.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const fs = require('fs');
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json'));

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The client is ready!');
})

client.login(config.token);
```